# Run time (Programmatically changes) Address of the service from client side

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a two services like 'http://192.168.1.4/zfsapi/api.php?wsdl' and 'http://192.168.1.5/zfsapi/api.php?wsdl'  which have same functionality but hosted in to different server at C# client side I created proxy of 'http://192.168.1.4/zfsapi/api.php?wsdl' this service. I want to change the address at run time of this service depending on the different serverIP address of the service.

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: You you want to do i am not getting through... Please clarify more details..

Comment: i want change endpont address of service from client side depending on diffrent server .

Comment: the service is hosted on the different server which having same functionality and we reference only one service reference at my client side

Comment: @viky i am not sure about what you are looking for, but you can do this by using 1 fixed IP and webservices will always be called to this IP.. now this IP will call you webservices every time with your dynamic services. As this IP is hosted at ur place you can manage it dynamically

Comment: You can point that all the request from first server to Second. Client will always be calling first server but first server will redirect it to second one.

Comment: @viky, have you tried using a config file for this? If the client application is a Winforms application you could also use "Settings" feature. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can create a client-side proxy class by specifying its binding and endpoint address:

```
// or instantiate whatever other binding you're using    
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None);

// define the endpoint address
EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.1.5/zfsapi/api.php");

// create your WCF client-side proxy based on those settings
YourServiceClient client = new YourServiceClient(binding, epa);
```

Once the client is created, you cannot change its endpoint address - if you need to use a new address, you need to instantiate a new instance of the client-side proxy class.

Comment: But what if YourServiceClient doesn't have a constructor with these two parameters?